# In which cases is finalize() actually USED?

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

I've found multiple posts stating when finalize() should NOT be used and that it shouldn't be used in general because nobody guarantees the the object will be garbage collected during the lifetime of the application (unless you actually need the object throughout the lifetime of the application, this is a memory leak in my book). But let's say I have a Java class that initializes something (does memory allocation and initialization) in native space through JNI. As far as I'm concerned, there two ways I can implement this:
1. Implement an init() and deinit() method in the class to do the native initialization and deinitialization. This has a down side that I have to take care of the object life cycle and can't leave that to the garbage collector (which is not very Java-like).
2. Do the initialization in the constructor and deinitialization in the finalize() method. This basically enables the objects to be automatically garbage collected like with any other Java class.

What I'm asking is - is there a reason for me not to go with number 2?

Thanks,
Nenad

Comment: All the same reasons: particularly, no guarantee when it'll be called. Generally, it's usual practice to manually manage native objects, and `try`-with-resources makes it much easier for some uses.

Comment: Using finalize to ensure you deallocate memory in your JNI code is a common use of finalize and is completely fine. I would use a combo of both ways.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html#finalize%28%29

Comment: Why is this downvoted? I think the question is completely legit...

Comment: @NESPowerGlove: If I'm using finalize() strictly for memory releasing, is the GC going to be invoked if a lot of memory is allocated in native space and not in Java space? Is GC guaranteed to be invoked periodically, because most of my memory allocations will be done in native space?

Answer (score 2):

> What I'm asking is - is there a reason for me not to go with number 2?

Well one reason would be that the native resource *won't* be release until the GC has reclaimed the Java object whose `finalize` method will reclaim it.

Whether this reason is actually relevant depends on the nature of the native resource.

---

Really, when you think about it, this is the same debate that the Java designers would have had about closing streams.

- They could have not provided a `close()` method, and left it entirely to a `finalize` method ... except that that would lead to problems with output stream not being flushed soon enough, and running out of "file descriptors".
- They could have left it entirely to the `close()` method ... except that if you did forget to `close()` a file (and there wasn't a `finalize` method) you would leak file descriptors ... permanently.
- Instead, they implemented both `close()` and `finalize`, and they implemented the latter to call the former.  Thus you get the advantage of closing when the program says so, and something to clean up<sup>1</sup> if it neglects to call `close()`.

<sup>1 - Of course, there can be problems if you rely on the stream `finalize` method for cleanup; e.g. if the stream remains reachable by accident, or if it doesn't get garbage collected soon enough, and you run out of file descriptors anyway.  And non-deterministic flushing out output could be a problem too.</sup>

---

> OK. What about when the resource in question is purely memory? Isn't that the same as garbage collecting then?

I don't see that.  True  garbage collection doesn't rely on you implementing a finalize method, or a close method, or something else that explictly releases stuff.

Comment: OK. What about when the resource in question is purely memory? Isn't that the same as garbage collecting then?
But I like the idea of implementing both, I'll probably go with that.

Answer (score 0):

Code execution doesn't necessarily release resources when the latter should be released. Therefore, I would use finalize as soon as you know that resources are no longer needed if these resources are significant. If resources are small don't use finalize because it comes with an overhead.